# Как получить IP, указанный в консоли команды ipconfig?

Tags: c#, ip

Пишу следующий код, чтобы узнать свой IP:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).First().MapToIPv4();
```

Но он не совпадает с тем, что выдает мне cmd->ipconfig. В чем может быть проблема и какой IP более точно относится ко мне?

Comment: Зачем вы вообще используете DNS?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?view=net-6.0

Comment: @PavelMayorov, этот пример в интернете значился как "актуальный"

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, буду пробовать

Answer (score -2):

А так?

```
string sHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipE = Dns.GetHostByName(sHostName);
IPAddress[] IpA = ipE.AddressList;
for (int i = 0; i < IpA.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IpA[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Я тоже думал перебрать их все, мне просто не понятно, какой тогда индекс соответствует тому единственному ip, который выдается в ipconfig, и какая тут вообще логика